# Symfony 2 (Doctrine) does not treat result as class object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
use AppBundle\Entity\classObject;

/**
 * @Route("route/sub/action", name="methodName")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function doMethod(Request $request)
{
    $content;
    $myClassObject = $this->returnObject();

    if ($myClassObject) {
        $myClassObject-> **NOTHING EXISTS...**
    } else { $content = '[{ "result":"0" }]'; }

    $response = new Response($content);
    return $response;
}
/*
 * @return classObject
 */
private function returnObject() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:classObject');
    return $repo->createQueryBuilder('o')->where('o.active LIKE :active')->setParameter('active', true)->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

The above example is not working, my database has an object which active is true. The value `$myClassObject` equals result from database where active is true. This is an entity class. However, it is not treated as an object/class after retrieving from the database. Functions like get/set cannot be accessed.

Comment: The LIKE operator is used for matching a string pattern, not boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `1` instead of `true` in the `active` parameter and use `equal` instead `LIKE` as follow:

```
   return $repo->createQueryBuilder('o')
      ->where('o.active = :active')
      ->setParameter('active', 1)
      ->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately hasn't made any difference. The object is returned by the database query whether LIKE or = and regardless of 'true' or '1'. The problem is: $myClassObject-> **NOTHING EXISTS...** (it is not treated as an object/class and has no function/variables)

Comment: Also to add PHPStorm is my IDE with Symfony integration.

Comment: @JordanDyckes What exactly are you saying? What is the type of the returned value? Is your question only about autocompletion in the IDE?

Comment: The returned value is a classObject as it states ' * @return classObject' the result $myClassObject is not null, so it proceeds. $myClassObject has nothing e.g get/set. However, issue has been resolved now after losing an entire days work. Now json_encode returns invalid JSON. Really wishing I never used Symfony, always issue after issue.